# Would a human with electric powers be able to use them to strengthen their muscles?

Tags: science-based, biology, magic, humans, electricity

I heard that electrical stimulation can lead to a similar effect to working out, so I was wondering if someone who can create and finely control electricity would be able to increase their physical strength like this, and if so how much? Would there be side effects? How long would it take? Would it be worth it?

In this scenario the person has precise enough control over electricity that they can sense
and trigger individual nerve impulses.

Comment: Not as much as you might think. I had electrical stimulators stuck to my leg eons ago when I damaged it skiing. Their purpose was to keep the leg muscles from atrophying. It's was uncomfortable and based on that experience I think the energy needed to build muscles would be quite painful and likely to burn the flesh. (BTW, please keep in mind you're allowed to ask only one question. Asking more than one is a reason to close a question. Click the "close" link to find out more.)

Comment: Yes, but not for the reasons you think. Electric stimulation just makes sure the muscles contract normally. So instead of electric stimulation, why not use them normally? The electric stimulation is for people who cannot do it normally or for people who dont want to be busy thinking about the training.

Comment: As JBH said electrical stimulators can help against muscle atrophy but they do not build significant muscle amounts. I remember the first time playing around with one, put a 10kg dumbell in your hand, turn the machine to full and the weight curls up without you trying lol. Maybe if their electrical power somehow allows faster nerve transmission, it will give them greater explosive strength.

Comment: If you're looking just for super strength, then muscles are not the way to go. You can use that kind of power to give them their super hero fit body and perhaps enhanced neural activity. But if we're talking pure force output you might be better off with a special gloves or a suit which would let them use exert force from an electromagnetic field onto the suit. If their control over electricity is really powerful and they can generate their own energy or store a pre-existing one somehow, then you could even do things outside the laws of physics.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, and hopefully [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6104107/) will help fill in some backstory on this answer. The current medical view is generally yes, EMS *can* help strengthen muscle tissue, and repair atrophy, but stimulating neurons isn't a replacement for the physical effects of exorcise.

Think of it like a nail gun: It's faster than a hammer, but you still need to bring in building materials, and flush out waste. [Muscles grow](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/319151) from a process of tearing down and rebuilding itself as it flexes to perform work, using hormones, insulin, and lactic acid, among many other things, to create conditions that thicken and strengthen the tissue.

That being said, there's no reason why this character couldn't enhance normal exertions like walking, blinking, and breathing, to strengthen those body parts respectively. Additionally, keep in mind that our thoughts are the result of millions of tiny electrical pathways buzzing around in our heads like rollercoasters. It could be interesting to explore the psychology of this metamorphosis, and how intelligence, reason, compassion, and joy might be affected.